# Formatting and transforming data in Python

Tags: python, formatting

I am trying to reformat somewhat inconsistent values (OCR) to a standard form based on a set of rules. These values come over typically as a fraction i.e. 4 3/4 but the values are sometimes polluted with other random characters i.e. 4 .3/4. The values can also be non fractional floats (4.75). The goal is to grab the values and produce the number; input = 'T  3/' output = 3. The values will never exceed 11.

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but this is what I have so far, and it works on most but it doesn't catch everything. Any help to help handle exceptions like 'T  3/' would be appreciated.

```
a = '  Y 3/'

def get_num(t):
    return str(''.join(ele for ele in t if ele.isdigit()))
t = get_num(a)
y = int(t)
z = a.split('.')[0]
print len(t)

if '/' in a:
    if int(str(y)[:1]) == 1 and int(str(t)[1]) != 1 and len(t) == 4 and t <1199:
        print '{}{} {}/{}'.format(*t)
    if int(str(y)[:1]) == 1 and int(str(t)[1]) != 1 and len(t) == 4 and t >1199:
        print '{} {}/{}'.format(*t[1:])
    if int(str(y)[:1]) != 1 and int(str(t)[1]) != 1 and len(t) == 3:
        print '{} {}/{}'.format(*t)
    if int(str(y)[:1]) != 1 and int(str(t)[1]) == 1 and len(t) == 3:
        print '{} {}/{}'.format(*t)
elif '.' in a and '/' not in a:
    if int(z) == 1 and len(z) == 1:
        print a.replace(' ','')
    if int(z) > 11 and len(z) > 1 and int(t[:1]) == 1:
        print a.replace(' ','')[1:]
    if int(z) != 1 and len(z) <= 2:
        print a.replace(' ','')

elif '.' not in a and '/' not in a:
    if int(str(y)[:1]) == 1 and int(str(t)[1]) != 1 and len(t) == 4 and t <1199:
        print '{}{} {}/{}'.format(*t)
    if int(str(y)[:1]) == 1 and int(str(t)[1]) != 1 and len(t) == 4 and t >1199:
        print '{} {}/{}'.format(*t[1:])
    if int(str(y)[:1]) != 1 and int(str(t)[1]) != 1 and len(t) == 3:
        print '{} {}/{}'.format(*t)
    if int(str(y)[:1]) != 1 and int(str(t)[1]) == 1 and len(t) == 3:
        print '{} {}/{}'.format(*t)
else:
    print(a)
```

Common Sample Inputs/Outputs (many more combos):

```
In: 4 3/4   | Out: 4 3/4
In: 4.75    | Out: 4.75 
In: T 3/    | Out: 3
In: 14 3/4  | Out: 4 3/4 (leading 1 does not belong >11
In: 4   .33 | Out: 4.33
In: 3 2./3  | Out: 3 2/3 
In: 3 ..33  | Out: 3.33
```

Essentially its a fraction if there is a '/' in the string even if it contains a '.'. If its not in the string, it's a decimal. If neither, then there is an opportunity there as well for some logic

Comment: for the case of "4 .3/4." are you expecting this to be 4.75 or 4.075?

Comment: Hey @FanScience, have you looked into the `fractions` python module? Also, can you format some example inputs at the bottom of your question?

Comment: @zerocool that should be 4.75, the OCR randomly inserts periods sometimes

Comment: @PeterDolan I took a look at the fractions module briefly as I was searching through posts that might help me but have not explored putting it in here other than light discovery. Adding sample inputs

Comment: How you looked into `re` library?

Comment: Thanks for sample. For sample inputs can you add expected output? Once I have that I can work on whipping something up in a couple of hours

Comment: @PeterDolan I just updated with some additional notes as well. Thx

Comment: @FanScience, one more question: do you want outputs as strings, or floats? For example, should "4 3/4" be returned as `"4.75"`, `"4 3/4"` or `4.75`?

Comment: Also, is it possible for there to be improper fractions? i.e. `4 4/3`?

Comment: @PeterDolan  floats would be the ultimate goal just to standardize. No improper fractions.

Comment: @FanScience answered below

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Alright @FanScience, got an answer here. It works with all the inputs you gave, but it's slightly brittle -- happy to try to expand if you find there are inputs that it doesn't get along with.

First I imported two helpful libraries:

```
import re
from fractions import Fraction
```

Next I defined a dictionary with your inputs + expected outputs, so I could write a function that tested my methodology:

```
expected_results = {
        "4 3/4": 4.75,
        "4.75": 4.75,
        "T 3/": 3,
        "14 3/4": 4.75,
        "4   .33": 4.33,
        "3 2./3": 3.67,
        "3 ..33": 3.33,
}
```

Next I got to writing the actual function -- let me know if you have any questions, as this is somewhat complex:

```
def generate_correct_float(to_convert):
    # Removes any alphabetical character (A, B, a, b...)
    to_convert = re.sub("[a-zA-Z]", "", elem)
    # Removes extra whitespace on either end
    to_convert = to_convert.strip()
    final_answer = 0

    if " " in to_convert: #two-part, ie 4 3/4
        primary_number, secondary_number = to_convert.split()
        final_answer += int(primary_number)
        if "/" in secondary_number: # Fraction case
            secondary_number = secondary_number.replace(".", "")
            secondary_number = secondary_number.strip("/")
            secondary_number = Fraction(secondary_number)
        else: #Decimal Case
            secondary_number = Fraction(int(secondary_number.replace(".", "")), 100)
        final_answer += round(secondary_number.__float__(), 2)
    else: # Single element, ie 3/
        final_answer = to_convert.strip("/")
        final_answer = float(final_answer)

    # Eliminate cases where we're higher than 11
    while final_answer > 11:
        final_answer -= 10

    return final_answer
```

Finally I wrote a wrapper function that tests inputs vs outputs and gives us a correct vs incorrect count:

```
incorrect = 0
for elem in expected_results:
    answer = generate_correct_float(elem)

    if answer != expected_results[elem]:
        print('------')
        print(elem)
        print(expected_results[elem])
        print(answer)
        incorrect += 1

correct = len(expected_results) - incorrect
print(f"correct: {correct}")
print(f"incorrect: {incorrect}")
```

Running this with our code gives us 7/7, all with floats!

Hopefully this helps -- let me know if there are any points of clarification I can make @FanScience

Comment: For downvoters, could you explain why? I'd like to get better at answering questions here.

Comment: This works pretty well, sir. I'm going to add a few handling rules but it is much cleaner. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it @FanScience. Lmk if you have any more questions, and if this answered yours please mark it as correct!